# Trying to merge separate address fields into one display field using AMPscript code

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to combine 6 address fields from a custom object to create one variable for one Main Address.  Is it possible to combine these fields if I create one address field?  New to AMPscript so trying to figure out if this is the easiest way to do this.

```
%%[
VAR @MainAddress, @Street,@Street2,@City,@State,@Zip,@Country
Set @MainAddress = "Main Address"
Set @Street = 'Street_1__c'
Set @Street2 = 'Street_2__c'
Set @City = 'City__c'
Set @State = 'State__c'
Set @Zip = 'Zip__c'
Set @Country = 'Country__c'

Main Address:%%=v(@MainAddress)=%%
endif
]%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the fact, that you are fetching the data using [RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://ampscript.guide/retrievesalesforceobjects/), puts everything in a different light. This function returns a rowset, meaning you have to use [Row](https://ampscript.guide/row/) and [Field](https://ampscript.guide/field/) functions, to get the single fields. I also assume, that you DO have the *AccountID* as a field in your sendable Data Extension:

```
%%[ 
VAR @SFRecords, @ID, @MainAddress, @Street,@Street2,@City,@State,@Zip,@Country
SET @ID = AttributeValue('AccountID') 
SET @SFRecords = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Reservation__c','Street_1__c','Street_2__c','City__c','State__c','Zip__c','Country__c','Check_in_Address__c','Household__c','=', @ID) 
SET @SFRow = Row(@SFRecords,1)
SET @Street = field(@SFRow,'Street_1__c') 
SET @Street2 = field(@SFRow,'Street_2__c')
SET @City = field(@SFRow,'City__c')
SET @State = field(@SFRow,'State__c') 
SET @Zip = field(@SFRow,'Zip__c')
SET @Country = field(@SFRow,'Country__c')
SET @MainAddress = Concat(@Street," ",@Street2," ",@City," ",@State," ",@Zip," ",@Country)
]%%
```

Going beyond above explanation is not within the scope of this site, as it expects a basic understanding of programming, and helps you when you are stuck. For more details on Ampscript, I will suggest looking at [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/ampscript-for-nondevelopers) and [Ampscript.guide](https://ampscript.guide/language/)

Comment: Hi Lukas, I appreciate your quick response, I am not getting an error when I am using your formula, but I am not getting any data to populate either.  I think it has to do in bringing in the data from the Custom Object, I am missing something when trying to combine them with Retrieve command. I am trying the following to get the data.  The field I set up in SF is Check_in_Address__c%%[ Set @ID = AccountID ]%%
%%[ RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Reservation__c','Check_in_Address__c,', 'Household__c','=', @ID)

endif

%%=v(@Mainaddress)=%%
]%% .  Where would I incorporate your code?

Comment: @Dalbanes - I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks Lukas, worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Concat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm) Function in ampscript. Use it like in the below code:

```
%%[ 
VAR @MainAddress, @Street,@Street2,@City,@State,@Zip,@Country 

Set @Street = 'Street_1__c' 
Set @Street2 = 'Street_2__c' 
Set @City = 'City__c' 
Set @State = 'State__c' 
Set @Zip = 'Zip__c' 
Set @Country = 'Country__c'

Set @MainAddress = Concat(@Street," ",@Street2," ",@City," ",@State," ",@Zip," ",@Country)

]%%
```

Let me know if this helps.